# To show that a certain function is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, sequence-of-function

In preparation for the analysis qualifying exam, I am solving problems from various sources. Following is the problem I'm having difficulty with.

Suppose $(f_n)$ is a sequence of measurable, complex valued functions defined on a measure space $\Omega$. Show that the function $h:\Omega\to\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ defined by

$$h(x)=\#\{n:f_n(x)=0\}$$

is measurable.

My thought was to verify the definition but no sigma algebras on either the domain or the co-domain are specified. I'm not sure where to begin. I would appreciate hints more than a complete solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try to write $h$ as a sum of characteristic functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you be so kind as to take a look at the answer below and help me fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the attempt, thanks to Daniel Fischer's hint. Corrections are welcome.

Define $E_n=\{x:f_n(x)=0\}$. Then

$$h(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\chi_{E_{n}}(x)$$

Since each $E_n$ is measurable, its respective characteristic function is also measurable and so is their partial sums. And finally, the limit of a measurable sequence (the sequence of partial sums in this case) is measurable. Thus $h$ is measurable.

Comment: Regarding the concern, for complex-valued or (extended) real-valued functions, unless a different $\sigma$-algebra is explicitly given the convention is to use the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. That is, such a function is measurable iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable for every open $U$.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say the solution is otherwise correct? May I accept it and get this question off the unanswered list?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, though since we have an infinite series it is perhaps better to use the word "limit". All partial sums are measurable, and thus the limit, i.e. $h$, is measurable too. And of course you may accept it, however if memory serves you must wait 48 hours before you can accept your own answer (there may be a reputation threshold, such that if you have more than $x$ rep you can do it faster).